# In-App Subscription Model

Tags: subscription

I've developed an iOS app that has a subscription model.

Apple offers a 7 - 30 day free subscription period that requires the user taps a button and starts the subscription.

Are there any good examples of in-app subscription flows that work well on iOS? Here are some permutations I've considered:

1. Block all access to app with modal until user enables subscription (this will start the n day free trial)
2. Provide a limited subset of features for the app, but encourage user to start n day free trial throughout the app.

Comment: Could you add some context?  You mention two models, which both seem good and perfectly useful.  What are the limitations of these, that cause you to want to find out other models?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? My guess is going to be an increase in subscriptions. The simple fact is, anything you put in place is going to be a barrier to X number of people who may have been interested in your app. Only user testing will bear out the facts, failing that Ilias has the best suggestion. We agonise over forcing people to register without cost. You're charging people. If someone in your organisation doesn't agree with the testing model, you'd do well to point out how important the decision can be.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use a third model: Let the user use the app with all features for a limited time (7 - 30 days). When that time has expired, the user will be left using only a limited set of features. This will make the user addicted to your awesome app and therefore (s)he will feel the pain of feature limitations witch will make her/him ending up paying for your app.

Users who do not want to pay will most probably already have uninstalled/stopped using your app before that limited time expires.

Don't forget to notify the user a few days prior to when the subscription starts. This will of course make a few users cancel the subscription, but that leaves you with a set of committed users who are going to stay with you for a while.